# How to get csrf token from get api and pass csrf token to another post api using REST Assured?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

How to get csrf token from get api and pass csrf token to another post api?

I have to perform login. For this I have to pass 3 parameters:

1. csrftoken
2. username
3. password

The csrftoken is received using **GET** *https://url.com/account/login* in form of response body in DOC format.

Comment: Can you share the sample request and response of csrftoken from the GET url.

Comment: Add the request, response and response header in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Request is :

[image]

Response is :
[image]

Response Header is :

[image]

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding an answer

Comment: Try using getCookie("csrftoken");